# logging in to server using Socket Programming

Tags: sockets, authentication, server

I am trying to write a code that connect our local server, log in to a webpage on that and retrieve some data. I could connect the server using the server IP and connect function. Now I need to log in on a webpage that accept the following format:

`addUPI?function=login&user=user-name&passwd=user-password&host-id=xxxx&mode=t/z`

I wrote something like this:

```
int ret= send(sock,"addUPI?funcion...&mode=t",strlen("addUPI?funcion...&mode=t"),0);
```

but it does not work. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: You really don't want to connect to the server using raw sockets.  Look for a library that implements an HTTP client for your platform.  What language are you using?

Comment: Try the [cURL libraries](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the right way to do HTTP.  For one thing, the typical HTTP lifecycle looks something like this (very abbreviated):

```
...Connect
>>> GET / HTTP/1.0
>>> Host: localhost
>>> Referrer: http://www.google.com
>>>
<<< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
<<< Date: Wed, 08 Apr 2015 05:21:32 GMT
<<< Content-Type: text/html
<<< Content-Length: 20
<<< Set-Cookie: ...
<<<
<<< <html><h1>Hello World</h1></html>
```

And that's assuming there are no redirects, SSL or other mystical protocol happenings.  So, just writing the string you specified above is going to result in a closed connection due to not following the protocol.

Really, you probably want to use a fully-baked HTTP library like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/), which manages all the protocol requirements.

I shamelessly adapted this example from the [curl website](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init(); 
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/addUPI?function=login&user=user-name&passwd=user-password&host-id=xxxx&mode=t");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```